# Spring @Bean method with parameters : how client of the method can know of them?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

As you know, we can create singleton bean as follow:

```
    @Bean(name = "localeResolver")
    public LocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver() {

        CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("ko"));

        return localeResolver;
    }
```

But for ContentNegotiationResolver, we've recommended to use the following code to instantiate a default ContentNegotiationResolver since spring 3.2

```
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {

        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setOrder(0);
        contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);

        List<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
        views.add(new MappingJackson2JsonView());
        contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setDefaultViews(views);

        return contentNegotiatingViewResolver;
    }
```

as you can see, the above method has the parameter, ContentNegotiationManager.
**Here is my question**: How client of the above `@bean` method can create a argument? and which value of properties does client inject to the argument `ContentNegotiationManager`?
spring framework was instructed to create a ContentNegotiation bean but not ContentNegotiationManger.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you asking because it doesn't work, or is it working and you're asking *how* it works? The client here is the Spring framework itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are placing the contentNegotiatingViewResolver on the spring context and it requires a ContentNegotiationManager as a constructor parameter, you have no choice but to inject one that also lives on the spring context.

If you want to let the client specify the ContentNegotiationManager, then you'll need to return a class with a method that the client can call. The easiest way I can think of doing this, is to wrap the method that creates the ViewResolver in a simple class, probably annotated with a @component annotation like so:

```
@Component
public class MyViewResolver {

    List<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();

    public ViewResolver getResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {

            ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
            contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setOrder(0);
            contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);

            List<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
            views.add(new CommonMappingJackson2JsonView());
            contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setDefaultViews(views);

            return contentNegotiatingViewResolver;

    }

}
```